# XPATH exclude more than one element/tag

Tags: xpath, html-parsing

I am having issues trying to extract text between two `div` tags in an XML.

Imagine I have the following XML:

```
<div class="default_style_wrap" >

<!-- Body starts -->
    <!-- Irrelvent Data -->
    <div style="clear:both" />
    <!-- Irrelvent Data -->
    <div class="name_address" >...</div>
    <!-- Irrelvent Data -->
    <div style="clear:both" />
    <!-- Irrelvent Data -->
    <span class="img_comments_right" >...</span>

    <!-- Text that I want to get -->
Two members of the Expedition 35 crew wrapped up a 6-hour, 38 minute spacewalk at 4:41 p.m. EDT Friday to deploy and retrieve several science experiments on the exterior of the International Space Station and install a new navigational aid.
    <br />
    <br />
The spacewalkers' first task was to install the Obstanovka experiment on the station's Zvezda service module. Obstanovka will study plasma waves and the effect of space weather on Earth's ionosphere.

    <!-- Irrelvent Data Again -->
    <span class="img_comments_right" >...</span>
    <!-- Text that I want to get -->
After deploying a pair of sensor booms for Obstanovka, Vinogradov and Romanenko retrieved the Biorisk experiment from the exterior of Pirs. The Biorisk experiment studied the effect of microbes on spacecraft structures.
    <br />
    <br />
This was the 167th spacewalk in support of space station assembly and maintenance, totaling 1,055 hours, 39 minutes. Vinogradov's seven spacewalks total 38 hours, 25 minutes. Romanenko completed his first spacewalk.
    <!-- Body ends -->
</div>
```

As it may not be reflective in the code, `default_style_wrap` is the parent of all those other irrelevant `divs` and `spans`. The relevant text to me is basically all of the tag-less text but as there are other tags in between as you can see, for instance `img_comments_right`, it is driving me nuts.

I tried the following as I saw in another post:

```
"//div[@class='article_container']/*[not(self::div)]";
```

but that seems not be returning any text at all, and even if it did, I wouldn't know how to also exclude the `spans`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You can use `or` operator for specifying multiple conditions for `not` operator
Like so:

```xml
not(expr1 or expr2)
```

Thus you can add `self::span` as another condition for `not` to exclude them from result ;

```xml
//div[@class='default_style_wrap']/*[not(self::div or self::span)]
```

---

PS: There seems to be issue with improper closing of `div` tags. Close them in a proper way.

Answer (score -1):

You should try the following query. It selects all following siblings of the `<span>` nodes, which are *text nodes*:

```
query = '//span[@class="img_comments_right"]/following-sibling::text()';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however what I am trying to get is everything *but* the spans and divs within the main container, i need the text outside of the tags.

Comment: Thats exactly what the query returns. The text outside the tags

Answer (score -1):

You can use this xpath:

```
//div[@class='default_style_wrap']/text()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to grab the text, using this XPath:

```
div[@class = 'default_style_wrap']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

It selects all `text()` nodes that are children of the *default_style_wrap* `<div>`, filtering empty (or whitespace-only) nodes out.

If you use a separate template, you can put each chunk neatly in its own paragraph, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class = 'default_style_wrap']/text()[normalize-space()]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>
```